# Best practice - Calling APIs & Services in Single page applications

Tags: architecture, single-page-application, microservices

I have a single page applications that needs to call a variety of web services and/or APIs. I would like to understand what is a generally agreed approach to making api or service calls from SPA. We currently have two approaches

1. For certain 3rd party APIs- we make direct calls from the single page application without a server side proxy. In order for this to work we have CORS enabled.
2. For other  API calls - we make calls to a proxy (wrapper) which is responsible for redirecting them to the appropriate endpoints.

The way we decide which approach to use is - if there is some kind of data manipulation thats needed before calling the 3rd party api - we use the proxy - else we make direct calls from the SPA. Is this a valid approach. Would you have any feedback on if the 1st approach is robust from a security point of view? In the 1st approach we have a http-only cookie that is being used as an access token to make calls to the 3rd party api. Does this make the API we are exposing vulnerable?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend that you proxify all your API calls.

Calling a 3rd party API is ok for some use cases, but not if you start having to deal with a lot of them.

Here are my key points:

- Interfacing APIs permits to concentrate the listing, organization and updates of the 3rd party APIs. It also makes easier to build your own tracking, stats and monitoring.
- You can reroute any API if it is down, and provide adequate error handling so that you avoid frustrating timeouts / ugly error messages for your customers due to that 3rd party API being down
- You isolate and secure your customers from outside service: yes if the 3rd party API is exploited by a malicious user (eg: returns 'bad' pictures', redirects the navigation...), you can filter it.
- It is easy to change ONE hostname for your API proxy, it is harder to change 20. If you want to migrate your application into closed environments (private networks) the API proxy will come as a real helper when it comes to all the issues with DNS, proxies, gateways, etc.
- You can offer your own standardized API which interfaces all the others: this will be an accelerator for developments. Take a look at **GraphQL** if that could help you perform both multi-API calls and result sizes optimizations.

Comment: thanks for your response. i should have been clearer - the 3rd party apis i talk  about are not exactly from a 3rd party - they are internal organisation APIs which my team has no control over - hence i called them "3rd party". But i agree with all the key points you raised.